Springboot + com.netflix.graphql.dgs - Not picking up the GraphQL schemas from the file system
On springboot: 3.4.0
Using this as a dependency:
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.graphql.dgs</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-dgs-spring-graphql-starter</artifactId>
 </dependency>

My graphql schemas are on the file system and I dont want to be picked up from the classpath:
I tried playing with both these properties and none of them seem to pick up the graphql schemas from the file system.
spring.graphql.schema.locations=file:${user.dir}/configurations/schema/
dgs.graphql.schema-locations=${user.dir}/configurations/schema

But if I move the .graphqls file into the src/main/resources/schemas, it gets picked up.
Whats that am I missing here?
